# UIText is open keyboard at start?

Tags: objective-c

I am using a code to a text field ,it works fine (with cocos2d also), but i cant understand why the keyboard is open when i start the app? i want it to be like that :

- when you open the app, you see a rect-which is the textfield(i dont know how to put that rect?? ) and ONLY when you touch it , it opens the keyboard and you can type .

any help to do this would be great .

my code:  (  `setText` is called in `init` )

```
-(void)setText
{

    myText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 120, 200, 90)];
    myText.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI / 2.0 );
    [myText setDelegate:self];
    [myText setText:@"yes"];
    [myText setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
    [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:myText];
    [myText becomeFirstResponder];
}


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [myText resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}



-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField *)textField {
    if(textField == myText) 
    {
        [myText endEditing:YES];
        [myText removeFromSuperview];
        NSString *result = myText.text;
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
    } 
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"textField did not match myText");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you put this:

```
 [myText becomeFirstResponder]
```

take it out and it should not bring the keyboard when your app is load.

Comment: becomeFirstResponder tells the system that you want to start editing the text field, so brings up the keyboard.

Comment: thanks, but my other question was how to bound the text field with a rect ?

Comment: the text field is also disappear after i hit the return key. why is that ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. You mean the text inside your text field disappeared or your text field itself disappeared?

Comment: The code specify what return key does is inside your function -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField(), and what you put there is just make the keyboard disappear, nothing to do with the textfield itself.

Comment: thanks a lot, i know that , the thing is that i have 2 text fields, and when the bool function is being called i get the uitextfield as argument .BUT ,   when i hit return, the text that i have already insert, is disappear ..